# Triggering via Asynchronous Callbacks

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, asynchronous

If an application executes a code block asynchronously and notifies the completion state in a callback, do these all leave execution on the main thread (the callback)?

What is the correct way to handle Core Graphics drawing and file operations in this callback?

I currently have these instructions running in the callback, but would like to trigger a thread to handle these instructions instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing any UI drawing, that has to be on the main thread. If you hvae these asynchronous blocks doing work now (ostensibly in a concurrent dispatch queue), why not just do all the work there, and when you have a finished product to show, only then message back on the main block. If your callback calls other methods in your class, the safest way to deal with concurrency is to define helper objects - small objects that take some input and product an output.

Create the helper, attach whatever data it needs, kick it off in a block on a queue, and when its done it messages back on the main thread that extracts the finished product, renders it, then deletes the helper object.

Comment: The code being done asynchronously is 1 step before and being done by a private library.

Comment: So then what exactly is your question? the private libary messages you back on some thread, maybe any thread. You now want to update your UI - so you can either test the thread you get messaged on "[NSThread isMainThread", and if so do the update then, or if not on the main thread dispatch a block on the main thread to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have much experience in Core Graphics, but I've done a good amount of work on blocks.

In my opinion, if your application executes a code block asynchronously (on a new thread), then it's a good practice to the make callback or notification on the main thread.